# How to Alter sequence for whole DB in Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, psql

I'm working with Django + PostgreSQL and I restored backup from my old DB dump on a current DB due to some reasons. Due to which the sequences of few tables were disturbed and I am not able to create a new Django superuser because of that. Can someone help me with how can I alter sequence of the whole db using any psql command.

> Error traceback if I've misinterpreted the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 183, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 168, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 151, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 80, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1045, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1054, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/orion/workspace/buddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1198) already exists.
```

Comment: your primary key constraint is violated in auth-user table. not because of sequences. it means django user mgmnt is creating a record with an existing primary key.

Comment: If the primary key comes from a sequence, you can use `setval()` to reset it.

Comment: Have you reset the sequence number since you restored your DB? you have to set sequence number to max primary key +1 and not back to initial value.

Comment: @user3911119 I haven't reset the sequence.

Comment: a remote possibility ... have u restarted your django processes. sometimes a range of sequences get reserved in app space to prevent round trips to DB. your db state should be consistent to your app state wrt sequence numbers.

Comment: @user3911119 I did `sqlsequencereset` and it worked. I think using the old db dump added a few more users which didn't update the tables for "auth_user_pkey" so it was kinda stuck to 1198 but it should be actually 1251. So running `sqlsequencereset` did the job